# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object in C# with oracle dbase

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am getting an error 
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
oracle Sqldeveloper code:(pl/sql)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE LOGIN_PROCEED 
(P_id  IN LOGIN.ID%TYPE,
P_NAME OUT LOGIN.USERNAME%TYPE,
P_PSWD OUT LOGIN.PASSWORD%TYPE
)
AS
BEGIN 
IF P_id=2 THEN
     SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD
     INTO  P_NAME,  P_PSWD  from  LOGIN WHERE ID = P_id;  
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Correct' );
 ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Wrong username or password' );
 END IF;   
 END LOGIN_PROCEED;

 try
    {
        _oracon.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = _oracon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "Login_Func";           
                       cmd.Parameters.Add("Return_Value",OracleDbType.NVarchar2,ParameterDirection.ReturnValue);
        OracleParameter P_ID = new OracleParameter();
        P_ID.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2;
        P_ID.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        P_ID.Value = 1;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(P_ID);

        OracleParameter P_name = new OracleParameter();
        P_name.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        P_name.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        P_name.Value = txt_username.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(P_name);

        OracleParameter P_Pswd = new OracleParameter();
        P_Pswd.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
        P_Pswd.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        P_Pswd.Value = txt_password.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(P_Pswd);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string a = dr[0].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("~/Transactions/intrafundtransfer.aspx");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw (ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        lbl_msg.Text = dr[0].ToString();
    }
    _oracon.Close();
```

Anyone can resolve my issue  Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
or suggest modifications in the code.I want to return value from stored procedure.

Comment: A procedure doesn't return anything; you have two OUT parameters which pass values back to the caller, but there is no return type. But you seem to be calling Login_Func, not the Login_Proceed you showed.

Comment: Why do you store a password in plain text and retrieve it from the database? That should be the first thing you correct.